# Is it possible to change my loadout in the middle of a heist?

Tags: payday-2

Me and my crew were playing Payday 2, running a Framing Frame overkill pro job.  We managed to complete day 1 and day 2 with full stealth, and we had just killed the last guard on day 3.  Unfortunately, one of the bullets went wild and [shattered a glass window.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130711/what-actions-result-in-the-police-being-called)

Even more unfortunately, that glass window was perfectly in the field of view of a camera, and I couldn't shoot the camera, because I was [answering the pager](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129160/how-does-the-smooth-talker-skill-work-when-other-players-are-involved/) for the dead guard.

Sure enough, the alarm went off.  So now we're stuck on Overkill difficulty, in our dashing, but very squishy 2-piece suits.

[image: two piece suit]

We didn't want to just give up the payday; we were so close.  Plus, it costs $3M to buy the Framing Frame contract from Bain, and even if we couldn't get the gold, we wanted the bag loot.  But that means we need to survive wave on wave of tan SWAT and special enforcers.  Which means we need good guns and good armor.  Which we aren't carrying.

**So...is there any way to switch loadouts in the middle of a heist?**

Comment: Why did this get 2 votes up? Okay as a beginner I get the question but it's not that hard to find out. It's not possible to change, However as your answer is saying: You can dropout

Comment: @loko - I didn't realize it would work until I saw someone do it. I'm putting it out there so that others know it works.

Comment: Yeah ok the answer is good

Comment: Just note that buying contracts uses up your offshore account, not your spendable money.  That $3M is almost nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change your armor in the middle of a heist.  While carrying an [Armor Bag](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Bag), you will wear a temporary two piece suit.  When it hits the fan, deploy your armor bag and then use it.  You will switch to the full armor that you selected in the loadout screen.  There is not currently a way to switch weapons, and it will require you to forgo any other deployables (ECM, Ammo, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

### If you're not the host, and drop-in is enabled, you can change loadouts in the middle of a heist.

It helps if you're friends with one or more of the other players, and it also helps if the host has set the game options to either private or friends-only.

Simply exit the heist and then reconnect (or have someone still in the game invite you back).  You'll be taken to the mission briefing screen, where you'll be given the chance to change your loadout before you reconnect.

(It's best if you synchronize your efforts so that all three non-hosting players don't leave the game at once.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way of changing anything in a heist is by using an armour bag. Of course Steve V.'s answer will work, however leaving and attempting to re-join sometimes can cause problems such as the heist not re-appearing on CRIME.NET.