# Is disconnecting and reconnecting a viable way to refill health and ammo during a heist?

Tags: payday-2

Related to [my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138492/is-it-possible-to-change-my-loadout-in-the-middle-of-a-heist), my group has proved that as long as you're not the host, it's possible to change your loadout in the middle of a heist, if you're dressed for stealth and things unexpectedly get loud.

However, that makes me think: let's say that you're running a combat-heavy heist like Watchdogs.  Suppose you're short on health and ammo, almost dead.  **If you disconnect from the game and then immediately reconnect** (perhaps by having one of your friends in the game or receiving an invite), **will you restart with full health and ammo?**

And, if so, as long as you're playing with friends who don't mind constant disconnect/reconnects, **is there any reason why you shouldn't do this all the time?**

Comment: One thing to consider is if you do this, and you had ammo/health (out or on you), you will lose it entirely. You will spawn in with nothing, and if you put a bag down, it goes away upon disconnect.

Comment: @Unionhawk - I think I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "you will spawn in with nothing."  If you select an ammo bag in your loadout, and then reconnect, you'll spawn with an ammo bag.

Comment: I know I've dropped connection, reconnected, and returned without the ammo bag I had been previously carrying before.

Comment: @Unionhawk - Interesting, your experience and mine do not correspond.  Further research needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will respawn with full health and full ammo, but gadgets are kind of tricky.

Here's the key thing.  If you drop down a Doctor's Bag, let's say, and decided to try disconnecting and reconnecting, without changing your gadget, when you reconnect to the very same session, you will NOT have a Doctor Bag with you.

However, if you switch your gadget, meaning swapping out the Doctor Bag to an Ammo Bag, ECM, First Aid Kit, Sentry, or Trip Mine, you'll be able to place them down as deployables.

Comment: Also worth noting:  when you disconnect, your dropped gadgets disappear.  So you can't use this trick to get infinite ammo bags out.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Exactly.  The game discourages you from dc'ing and rc'ing just to get extra deployables in.